# Need help identifying the audio connectors on LCD controller boards

Tags: identification, connector

I ordered two LCD controller boards for some DIY projects.  The audio connectors were advertised as JST PH2.0 connectors, but they are not. Now I have a hard time identifying the connectors and the Chinese seller stays radio silence on this topic. Googling for the board specifications also turned out to yield no real information besides "audio connector."

These connectors are really tiny, and I was not able to measure the pitch of the pins. Here are some photos I hope are good enough to identify the type of the connectors.

Board 1 (labeled: PCB800661V9-1HDMI) has this connector:

[image]

Board 2 (labeled: HBT556-WTH-A01) has this even smaller connector:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try looking at JST or Molex's catalogs for things that look similar? As for the pin pitch, try getting some cheap electronic calipers to measure them that way.

Comment: Pin pitch is a critical measurement. Without that no-one's really going to be able to help you much.

Comment: Board 1 looks like it might be a JST clone, possibly compatible.

Comment: you say `I was not able to measure the pitch of the pins.` ... why not? ... the top picture shows the board on top of graph paper ... you could easily use the graph paper as reference

Comment: I think that I managed to get the pitch: 1.25mm (could also be 1.2mm for the second board)

Comment: That's the pitch for "board 2". What about the pitch for "board 1"? Also, more pictures of the connector in board 1", please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Board 2"

Thank you for the great pictures and for the pitch. They allowed me to identify it using my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&f=discrete_1row_w2b_conn_1p2&s=Panelmate). It's a Molex Panelmate. You can get the housing for the plug [here](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0511460400/356054).

[image]